# postgresql: large insert duration

Tags: postgresql

The database is postgresql 9.3.

There is a big table, with 70 more columns.
The use case would do 700 inserts per second, and each insert takes one row.

Here is some key items in the postgresql.conf:

```
shared_buffers = 1024MB # the system memory is 8096MB in total
work_mem = 32MB
maintenance_work_mem = 128MB

bgwriter_delay = 20ms

synchronous_commit = off

checkpoint_segments = 64
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

effective_cache_size = 4096MB

log_min_duration_statement = 1000
```

The log would show that the duration of some inserts exceed 1 second, after the number of rows reaches about ten million.

Anybody help?

Comment: how many rows in each insert?

Comment: How often do you commit? Have you considered using the `COPY` command?

Comment: @LukasEder, mostly it would be constantly at 700 rows/sec. It's not feasible to use COPY, because the data is not predefined or provisioned, and it's generated on demand by clients, moreover, the insert would be associated with some triggers to do business logic.

Comment: How many indexes do you have on that table? Index maintenance is one of the main factors why inserts go slow.

Comment: It might also be that this generates to much I/O. One option to improve performance is to move the WAL directory (pg_xlog) to a different hard disk (how many disks does your server have?)